# Note taking app for teams

Tags: webapp-rec

I use the SimpleNote website all the time for personal use. I'd like to use something like it to collaborate with my team at work. I tried setting up a a wiki once, but the new/(navigate to existing page -> edit) -> save page cycle was annoying for just jotting down a sentence or two, and keeping things organized started to be too much work. My goal is to reduce the friction for documenting things to nil.

Here's what I'm looking for:

- Search as the primary navigational interface
- Auto-save
- Fast. It takes 5-10 seconds to open a Google Doc and start editing. SimpleNote loads from a cold start in 3 seconds.
- Bonus points if I can host it on a server in our network.
- More bonus points if it allows login with a Google Apps account

I saw a Rails app that did something like this with a grid of index cards once, but I don't remember what it was called.

Comment: What's wrong with Google Docs? Multiple people can edit a single document at the same time.

Comment: It's not very fast to open, and organization is flat. It becomes unwieldy and hard to navigate when a few hundred notes are appended to it.

Comment: Discrete notes with search is easier.  Multiple people don't need to edit the same note most of the time, anyway. Think internal knowledge base. I'm looking for something with a workflow more akin to [SimpleNote](http://web.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/sshot_3.png) or [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/features.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of hunting, I found [Trello](http://trello.com/). It's not strictly a note taking application, but it does everything I listed in the bullet points except for having a local install option. There'a an API available, and an export feature is being worked on, so I'm OK with that.

It also allows you to sort notes into columns, which is nifty. Hopefully it doesn't fall apart when there's hundreds of notes on a board.

Answer (score 0):

You might have been thinking of [OpenNote](https://github.com/FoxUSA/OpenNote), which is a self-hosted OneNote alternative. Open source, very quick and with some tweaking (it's open source) you could probably integrate Google Apps API.

Comment: OpenNote didn't exist when I asked the question! The webapp I was thinking of appears to be [Makandra Cards](https://makandracards.com/)

Comment: @James Huh, I'd never seen that one before. OpenNote, funnily enough, fills all of your requirements, so it might work as well if not better!